# Adding number to duplicate uploaded file in PHP

Tags: php

I'm working on a simple PHP script that adds a number to a duplicate uploaded file and increments that number however many times the same file is uploaded (e.g. file.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt etc.). I've tried this so far, but it's not working properly. It only allows me to upload one duplicate file. (e.g. file.txt, 2file.txt). It doesn't let me upload anymore.

fileupload.html

```
<form action="fileDuplicate.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Select file to upload:
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
</form>
```

fileupload.php

```
<?php
$counter = 1;
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$increment = $target_dir .$counter++.basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

if (file_exists($target_file)) {
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $increment );
echo "<br>";
} else {
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
}
?>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic: _“Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.”_

Comment: How do you get the file name in the first place? Showing us some code would tell us how you do it now, so we can help you to add this new feature.

Comment: I just edited my OP.

Answer (score 1):

This should be your `PHP` code:
It increments everytime a file does not exist and keeps checking if a file exists.
It uploads the file with a name that doesn't exist.
**fileupload.php**

```
<?php
$counter = 1;
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

if (file_exists($target_file)) {
   $exists = true;
   $increment = $target_dir .$counter.basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
   while($exists){
      if(file_exists($increment)){
         $counter++;
      }
      else{
         $exists = false;
      }
    }
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $increment );
    echo "<br>";
}
else {
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As PHP restricts the duplicate file upload you can use `time()`function in the
 line of `$target` variable as `$target_file = $target_dir .time(). basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);` and after adding this there will be no need of writing the `if` `else` condition and adding a `$increment` variable in the code.
Because `time()` function adds a file with as small as time even micro sec considered and that's what will make your file stay in the folder.